# Disable div inside a draggable container element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/SaGtw/8/

Okay. So I want the #drag-box to drag, which is done easily. But I don't want the #element-1 to drag along with it but I still want the element-1 to be inside the #drag-box div.

```
<div id="drag-box">
    <div id="element-1">HECK YA!</div>
    <div id="element-2">HECK NO!</div>
</div>

$('#drag-box').draggable();
```

Is it possible? Can it be done? Sorry if it sounds too complicated.

Comment: Do you want only drag the div container but not its div elements like this http://jsfiddle.net/SaGtw/11/?

Comment: i have updated my jsfiddle, it might help you understand me better. And no, I want the elements to be inside the <div><element-1></div>...but I want the output to be the same as u have shown me...sorry if it sounds too complicated

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want element-1 inside draggable box if you dont want that div to move? If you define div draggable it is logical that elements inside that div also move. Why dont you put element-1 div outside draggable div, and element-2 inside?